# Getting synxtax error when trying to echo sql results as json datatype

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm trying to output the sql results of the statement in json datatype, but an error was prompt `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`, I have checked my sql statement and try to executed in sql editor and it works, but im not sure why it doesnt work when im trying to echo it in the browser.

So i have a big switch statement block, and this is a small part of it, so basically when i type `http://localhost/w11/local-html/part_1/api/schedule` it should output json datatype by taking in the arguments from the url like `api/schedule` and `api` is `arg_1` and `schedule` is `arg_2`.

```php
case 'api':
        {
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            switch ($param2) {
                case 'schedule':
                {
                    switch ($param3) {
                        case '':
                        {
                            try {
                                $sqlQuery = "SELECT room, type, title, day, time FROM sessions INNER JOIN slots ON sessions.slotsID = slots.id";
                                $response = new JSONRecordSet();
                                $response = $response->getJSONRecordSet($sqlQuery, "");

                                echo $response;
                            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                echo "Connection Failed:" . $e->getMessage();
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            //do something
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
```

This is the function for `getJSONRecordSet`

```php
class JSONRecordSet extends RecordSet {

    function getJSONRecordSet($sql, $params = null) {
        $queryResult = $this->getRecordSet($sql, $params);

        $recordSet = $queryResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $nRecords = count($recordSet);
        if ($nRecords == 0) {
            $status =  200;
            $message = array("text" => "No records found");
            $result = '[]';
        }
        else {
            $status = 200;
            $message = array("text" => "");
            $result = $recordSet;
        }
        return json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
                'data' => array(
                    "RowCount"=>$nRecords,
                    "Result"=>$result
                )
            ),
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
    }
}
```

And the parent class

```php
abstract class RecordSet {
    protected $conn;
    protected $queryResult;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = pdoDB::getConnection();
    }

    function getRecordSet($sql, $params = null) {
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $this->queryResult = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $this->queryResult->execute($params);
        }
        else {
            $this->queryResult = $this->conn->query($sql);
        }
        return $this->queryResult;
    }
}
```

So, how do i tackle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code.
Since `SyntaxError: JSON.parse` is a JS error you should just check what data is passed to it. Check the raw response to your request and do some debugging.
This is probably a problem with your db connection or your $param2 or $param3 conditions are not met.